# Thin processes not starting after reboot on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, startup-scripts, thin

Well, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 and I have Thin installed by

```
gem install thin
sudo thin install
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults
```

and I have my configs at `/etc/thin`.

But after system reboot thin processes are not started unless I run `sudo service thin start`.

While running `sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults` I got a warning:

```
update-rc.d: warning: thin stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB Default-Stop values (S 0 1 6)
```

But after changing `# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6` to `# Default-Stop:      0 1 6` (without `S`) warning dissappeared. But this doesn't solve the problem.

Aso tried to reinstall thin, but problem still appears.

My Rails application thin log says:

```
>> Writing PID to tmp/sockets/shashechki_thin.0.pid
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on /home/deploy/projects/shashechki/shared/sockets/shashechki_thin.0.sock, CTRL+C to stop
>> Writing PID to /home/deploy/projects/shashechki/shared/pids/shashechki_thin.0.pid
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on /home/deploy/projects/shashechki/shared/sockets/shashechki_thin.0.sock, CTRL+C to stop
>> Exiting!
```

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour on Debian Wheezy and Thin installed with `thin install`. After trying many configurations and several update-rc.d setups I bypassed by putting the line `/etc/init.d/thin start` in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: You just put `/etc/init.d/thin start` before `exit 0`? If so this doen't help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using RVM you have to create an rvm wrapper for thin with

```
rvm wrapper <ruby_version>@<gemset> bootup thin
```

and edit DAEMON variable at `/etc/init.d/thin`. The actual solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376785/532252)